# Calculating average of vectors using templates

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, variadic-templates

I made a simple function that takes 2 `std::array` and returns another `std::array` with the average values of the values in the `std::arrays`s.

```
template<typename T, std::size_t N>
std::array<T, N> average(const std::array<T, N>& a1, const std::array<T, N>& a2)
{
    std::array<T, N> array;
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < N; ++i)
        array[i] = (a1[i] + a2[i]) / 2;

    return array;
}
```

Works perfectly. Now I would like to calculate the average of *N* vectors. So I made this

```
template<typename T, std::size_t N, typename... Ts>
std::array<T, N> average(const Ts&... args)
{
    std::array<T, N> result;
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < N; ++i)
    {
        T addedValues = 0;
        for (const auto& array : { args... })
            addedValues += array[i];

        result[i] = addedValues / sizeof...(args);
    }

    return result;
}
```

Which also works, but I have to specify the resulting template arguments

```
std::array<int, 3> a{ 1, 2, 3 };
std::array<int, 3> b{ 3, 4, 5 };

auto c = average<int, 3>(a, b); //'<int, 3>' not good, possible without?
```

I couldn't think of another way, can somebody help me please?

Comment: I'd suggest you to take iterators (begin and end), or range/span, that way you're not restricted to `std::array<>`, but you can use all container types.

Comment: @lorro Good point, will do :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Provided that you'd also made the necessary changes in the body of the template function. You could change the signature of your template function as follows:

```
template<typename T, std::size_t N, typename... Ts>
std::array<T, N> average(std::array<T, N> const &arr, const Ts&... args)
```

This way you wouldn't have to specify the template arguments explicitly and template argument deduction would deduce `T` and `N` and thus you could call your `average` template function as:

```
std::array<int, 3> a{ 1, 2, 3 };
std::array<int, 3> b{ 3, 4, 5 };

auto c = average(a, b);
```